# Trimming .csv, removing it's duplicated and mapping to the original .csv not trimmed

Tags: bash, awk

I am facing a problem with .csv in bash.

I have a .csv like bellow:

```
dog,1, yellow, ball
cat, 2,green, skate
dog, 3 , yellow,   ball  
cat  , 4   , green, skate
dog, 5, yellow, ball
cat   , 6, green, skate
```

Where, a key is formed by columns, 1,2 and 4.
I have to first, make a copy of this .csv with all rows trimed (without whitespaces) and than I have to delete all duplicated rows, but mapping the rows to the original .csv, with the original whitespaces.

I am trying like:

```
awk '{sub(/^ +/,""); gsub(/, /,",")}1' input.csv >> temp.csv #to do the trim
```

That should result in:

```
dog,10,yellow,ball
cat,10,green,skate
dog,10,yellow,ball  
cat,10,green,skate
dog,10,yellow,ball
cat,10,green,skate

awk -F, 'dup[$1,$2,$4]++' temp.csv #to get the duplicated
```

resulting in:

```
dog,10,yellow,ball
cat,10,green,skate
```

But im stock in the mapping to the original .csv part.
**Please, pay attention that the original is not "regular" spaced, the expected result it's just the first two rows.**
When I have to get the expected output:

```
dog,10, yellow, ball
cat, 10,green, skate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this om your original file with the white spaces:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' '{orig=$0; gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} !seen[$1,$2,$4]++{print orig}' file
dog, 10, yellow, ball
cat, 10, green, skate
```